# Execute find and cp command through shell_exec in PHP

Tags: php, linux

I am currently facing an issue. When I am executing command (`find /home/vivek36/ -name '*$indexnumber*.wav'  -exec cp {} /home/main/backup \;`) from terminal. then it executes. But when I am executing this command from `shell_exec()` in PHP, It does not execute.I am executing php script from root users. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Why don't you use the php functions instead of the shell commands?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Or any of them

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Actually, There are multiple directories within which many wav files are available. So we do not know the exact file locations. Also I am fetching $indexnumber from database.

Comment: I don't see that as a problem. You can use variables in glob, and there are several "recursive globs" in the web.

http://thephpeffect.com/recursive-glob-vs-recursive-directory-iterator/

Comment: Are you running the PHP script from the command line?  Or, are you running the PHP script through your web server?

Comment: In your PHP script, try changing the shell_exec statement so like so:  shell_exec("echo find /home/vivek36/ -name '*$indexnumber*.wav'  -exec cp {} /home/main/backup \; 2>&1");  This will echo any output from the command, including any errors or warning that would normally be sent to stderr.  Perhaps something in the output will shed some light on why it's not working.

Comment: @mti2935 I would not recommend using shell commands if there is a php function for it.